# Parsing what an automatically generated select element in ASPX is doing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm trying to make sense of the following `select` element :

```
   <select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentItems$ddlResponseRange id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentItems_ddlResponseRange" class="Content" style="width:11%;">
```

This is all automatically generated code, correct( ie like ct100 ) ?  What are the $ symbols doing - are they for expression bindings? FYI the ddl here means "drop-down list".

Comment: `$` is just separator here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` and `_` are used as separators between the server-side ID of the control, `ddlResponseRange`, and the server-side IDs of its parent controls that are of type [`INamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) (typically `<asp:content>` controls).

A control by itself on a page, right inside a `<form runat="server">` does not have attributes like that. But when you start using master pages, or data binding controls, then you are using controls that implement `INamingContainer`. This interface is like a marker, and it instructs the ASP.NET runtime to start adding the control's server-side ID to that of its child controls. This is necessary to guarantee unique name and ID attributes in the generated HTML.

Ultimately this infrastructure is what supports ASP.NET Web Forms post back mechanism and client-side scripting.

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0 or later, you can actually influence the way client-side IDs are generated by ASP.NET. See [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) for different ways to configure the client-side IDs.

Answer (score 1):

It's all just one big string.  From the point of view of HTML, they're all valid characters to make up the value of an attribute, so in that sense it's "correct".

As for trying to use the id/name value yourself, or to rely on assumptions about the name/id based on that structure, I'd suggest avoiding that.  I find it preferable to pretend that ASP will generate a random name/ID that I can't use, despite the fact that in reality it's just the IDs of all elements from that item up to the root.  If you find yourself writing out ID values like that yourself, you're probably doing something wrong.

As for why it follows that convention instead of just actually assigning a random ID/Name (or none at all) is so that it can re-use it to correlate the HTML response to the structure of of items in memory.  It's also important to ensure that IDs are unique per page, and by using this structure it means that APS ID values only need to be unique among sibling elements.